# How to save a Jsoup Document to an HTML file?

Tags: java, jsoup, document

I have used this method to retrieve a webpage into an `org.jsoup.nodes.Document` object:

`myDoc = Jsoup.connect(myURL).ignoreContentType(true).get();`

How should I write this object to a HTML file?
The methods `myDoc.html()`, `myDoc.text()` and `myDoc.toString()` don't output all elements of the document.

Some information in a javascript element can be lost in parsing it. For example, "timestamp" in the source of an Instagram media page.

Comment: What elements are you missing when calling `myDoc.html()`?

Comment: Some elements might be removed or parsed differently when you use Jsoup to fetch it. Use a whitelist to fix it!

Comment: @cy3er I added an example. In this case, alkis's solution works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that there are elements that are ignored, must be due to the attempt of normalization by Jsoup.

In order to get the server's exact output without any form of normalization use this.

```
Connection.Response html = Jsoup.connect("PUT_URL_HERE").execute();
System.out.println(html.body());
```

Answer (score 28):

Use `doc.outerHtml()`.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public void downloadPage() throws Exception {
        final Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.net").execute();
        final Document doc = response.parse();

        final File f = new File("filename.html");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, doc.outerHtml(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

Don't forget to catch Exceptions. Add dependency or download Apache commons-io library for easy and quick way to saving files in UTF-8 format.